# Managing cognito users attributes from Lambda -- must they sign in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have done lots of get / set attributes work client side with the Cognito SDK, but now I have the need to be able to modify a user's custom attribute from the backend via Lambda functions (within a step function).

But in the client side version of the process, there is a step where I have to retrieve the current Cognito user, which is available because they had previously authenticated. Here's that code:

```
var poolData = this.poolData;
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
      var attributeList = [];
      var attribute = {
          Name : attr,
          Value : value
      };
      var attribute = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(attribute);
      attributeList.push(attribute);
      console.log("attributeList", attributeList);

      cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributeList, function(err, result) {
        callback(err, result);
      });
    });
}
```

But in the backend version of this, i'm technically administering a user.

So, how would I modify a user's attributes data from a lambda function? where the user isn't necessarily signing in first?

Answer (score 5):

You can't update the attributes on the user as you point out because you do not have a token for that user.

Instead use the `adminUpdateUserAttributes` on `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` that takes a username in the parameters and updates the attributes.

This will require you to have the correct permissions on your Lambda execution role since that will be used for the SDK call. So you need permissions for your lambda to edit the coginito attributes.

Documentation of the call: [adminUpdateUserAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property)